Tflite installation error in google colab
tflite-model-maker installation error.
When trying to install tflite-model-maker in google colab
ERROR: Cannot install tflite-model-maker==0.1.2, tflite-model-maker==0.2.0, tflite-model-maker==0.2.1, tflite-model-maker==0.2.2, tflite-model-maker==0.2.3, tflite-model-maker==0.3.3, tflite-model-maker==0.3.4, tflite-model-maker==0.4.0, tflite-model-maker==0.4.1, tflite-model-maker==0.4.2 and tflite-model-maker==0.4.3 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.
